# Filter based on counts django annotate query

Tags: python, django

I need to filter records based on total counts of records for vehicle_owner_organization_id (non distinct) before the first annotate, i.e if total counts in the collection for vehicle_owner_organization_id are greater than 1, then only go ahead with the following query getting monthly distinct counts. Is there an easy way to do this. Or do I need to run another query to filter.

```
values = ['month', 'city_code']
transacting_users = list(FieldOpsBooking.objects.using(
    'analytics').filter(**filter_query).annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('pick_up_at')).values(*values).annotate(
    count=Count(
        'vehicle_owner_organization_id', distinct=True)).values(*values,
                                                                'count'))
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
values = ['city_code']

FieldOpsBooking.objects.using('analytics').filter(**filter_query).values(
    *values, month=TruncMonth('pick_up_at')
).alias(
    ccount=Count('vehicle_owner_organization_id')
).annotate(
    count=Count('vehicle_owner_organization_id', distinct=True)
).order_by(*values, 'month').filter(
    ccount__gt=1
)
```

Comment: I needed to filter based on counts of vehicle_owner_organization_id before the first annotate, only working on counts greater than 1 (non distinct).

Comment: @AkshayHazari: than you make an alias for non-unique counts, or you use another `.annotate` (for versions prior to 3.1).